# How to get events between the current time and from the given time from mysql with ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i got a Event model and table and its

```
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :segmentation_id

  t.datetime :login_screen
  t.datetime :item_added_to_cart
  t.datetime :purchase_screen
  t.timestamps
```

this is my migration file.

In my view, I have a form in which i'm trying to create a new segment based on the user's input.I' m getting events and a date range.Events are column names of my Event Table except foreign keys and timestamp of creation.

So user will be able to select one of those.

Lets say user entered login_screen as first event and gave 7 as a date range, I need to get the login_screens event between current time and 7 days before of this current time.Since i got a user_id i got access for which user did that event anyway.All i need to do is get events based on the given date range.

I really don't want to use mysql code to do this, and I'm still a total newbie for rails.

Comment: So tl;dr is that you want to fetch records with `login_screen` within last week?

Comment: @MarekLipka , no the event name and the date range will come from the user , but basically yeah I want a event record between a given date range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do, given `range_start` and `range_end` are `Time` or `Date` objects provided by user:

```
Event.where(login_screen: range_start..range_end)
```

Comment: can you elaborate it a bit more?How do i give dynamic input as range_start  or event name?

Comment: @railsnewbie what do you mean by 'dynamic input'? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: as i explained in my comment, user may select one of the three events, and i m getting the input without a problem where I can use it as params[:segmentation][:first_event] its not login_screen it may be any of them.The other thing I'm getting from the user is date range, so i guess we can say that range_end is the Time.current but range_start will be i guess something like Time-params[:segmentation][:date_range]

Comment: hey dude, i'v been looking for a documentation but i couldn't manage to find any range_start or range_end method.Can you help me a bit

Comment: @railsnewbie, let me quote myself: 'given `range_start` and `range_end` are `Time` or `Date` objects provided by user'.

Comment: sorry for another question but no matter what i do i couldn't give first_event as a parameter. I tried to give it with to_sym and than i tried it with "#{firstEvent}" as firstEvent = params  but no matter what i do it didn't work, i can see first_event perfectly in my params tho, what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: @railsnewbie did you try `params[:first_event]`?

Comment: params first event is null anyway, the event name is stored in params[:segmentation][:first_event] and yes i did try it

Comment: @railsnewbie so how does your `params` hash look like?

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NCa+q1XojsKpB+VJwtIYxGYoxSIBE8M8a92E6X+FApU=", "segmentation"=>{"segmentation_name"=>"hello world", "date_range"=>"3", "first_event"=>"item_added_to_cart", "did_the_event"=>"true", "second_event"=>"purchase_screen"}, "commit"=>"Create Segmentation"}   looks like this

Answer (score 1):

putting to your code:-

```
data = Event.where("login_screen>= ? AND login_screen <= ?",Time.now ,login_screen)
```

**more better way**

```
@selected_date=params[:login_screen]
Event.where(:login_screen => Time.now.beginning_of_day..@selected_date.end_of_day)
```

...give it a try as the way u need

Comment: that doesn't make any sense, params[:login_screen] does not even exist.

if you meant params[:segmentation][:login_screen] its just a string where I keep the event name. it has nothing to do with date